# I am getting an error on shader graphs/Master on Unity URP 2022.3.4f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, game-development, urp

I have created URP fullscreen Shader Graph but i am having an error when i open shader graph tab on Unity. I am started to learn use custom shaders in unity but i did not understand why this problem occurs.
[image]
[image]

I deleted the library folder and imported again but this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: It maybe something to do with the name of any parameters.   I had some funky results from that. Try making them really simple like a,b etc

Comment: It directly gives error without creating or doing anything in shader graph editor. It gives when i click shader graph editor for fullscreen shader graph. for other shader graphs there is no problem

Answer (score 2):

I handled the situation by changing my OS language and regional format to US English.